# Pyspark: check if the consecutive values of a column are the same

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe with the following format:

```
ID    Name  Score  Rank  
1     A     10     1
1     B     20     2
2     C     10     1
2     C     12     2
3     D     11     1
4     E     12     1
4     E     13     2
```

goal is to find those ids where name is not the same for ranks 1 and 2, and if it is the same or there is only one name available, then filter those out. I think I can achieve that by creating another dataframe where I groupBy ID and then count name, left join with this dataframe and filter those with count < 2 but that's too hacky and I was wondering if there is a better way of doing this using windows functions. So the above would look like this after filtering undesired rows:

```
ID    Name  Score  Rank  
1     A     10     1
1     B     20     2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I understood that each ID has 2 rows at most, we can use a trick with `min` and `max` functions on a string variable and compare them; the trick being that min and max of a same string value would be equal.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w = Window.partitionBy('ID')

df = (df
  .withColumn('Name1', F.min('Name').over(w))
  .withColumn('Name2', F.max('Name').over(w))
  .withColumn('n_rows', F.count('*').over(w))
  .filter( (F.col('Name1') != F.col('Name2')) & (F.col('n_rows') > 1) )
  .select('ID', 'Name', 'Score', 'Rank')
)

df.show()
+---+----+-----+----+
| ID|Name|Score|Rank|
+---+----+-----+----+
|  1|   A|   10|   1|
|  1|   B|   20|   2|
+---+----+-----+----+
```